# Count specific word in file with

Tags: python

Im trying to count the number of occurrences of a word in a comma seperated file, using python.

I have a file that contains strings like this:

```
path/to/app1,app1,fail,my@email.com,logfile.log
path/to/app2,app2,success,my@email.com,logfile.log
```

I want to find the out how many times "fail" is in the file.

I tried several things including

```
for line in lines:
   if line.split(',') == "fail":
       fails += 1
```

Comment: If this is csv format, please use the csv module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is comparing lists (which are the result of a `str.split`) to the string `fail`, what you want to do is check if fail exists in these lines:

```
for line in lines:
   if "fail" in line.split(','):
       fails += 1
```

This code assumes `fail` can appear at most once, between commas.

The **correct** way to do this is using the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
fails = 0
with open("logfile.log") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for item in row:
            if item == "fail":
                fails += 1
print fails
```

You can also use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
with open("logfile.log") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        counter.update(row)
print counter['fail']
```

Comment: You could, but what if you have a string in the file that reads "This thing just **fail**ed"? You shouldn't make  a parser when a parser was made for you. This follows the Don't Repeat Yourself principle.

Answer (score 0):

Not the optimum solution but works

```
f = open("C:/Users/Superman/Desktop/krypton.log")
data = f.read()
fail_count =0
no_spaces = data.replace(' ', '')   #can use .strip() also to remove spaces
x = no_spaces.split(',')

for word in x:
  if word == 'fail':
    fail_count += 1
print (fail_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def specific_word_count(text, specific_word):
    return len(text.split(specific_word)) - 1
```

input：

```
specific_word_count('abcdabcdabcd','a')
```

output：

```
3
```