# How do I create a counter that ticks based on the number of words I replace?

Tags: python

I have a list of words and an email I need to censor. I am only supposed to censor the first 2 instances of any of the words in the list. Here is my function.

```
negative_words = ["concerned", "behind", "danger", "dangerous", "alarming", "alarmed", "out of control", "help", "unhappy", "bad", "upset", "awful", "broken", "damage", "damaging", "dismal", "distressed", "distressed", "concerning", "horrible", "horribly", "questionable"]

def censor_limit(text, new_text, lst):
  counter = 0
  with open(text) as read_file:
    with open(new_text, 'w') as write_file:
      for line in read_file:
        line = line.lower()
        for word in lst:
          if counter < 2:
            if word in line:
              line = line.replace(word, '***')
              counter +=1
        write_file.write(line)
```

My problem is that if a word shows up more than once in one line, both of them are replaced and the ticker only goes up by one. I know I can add 'count=1' to my replace method, but I'm unsure how to have the function check several times for the word then, rather than moving on to the next line.

Comment: you can count the words in this line before editing it, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38401151/11483506

Answer (score 1):

You can use re.findall to get all the matches in the text. Then, use that value to know if you need 0,1 or 2 replaces. Then, replace the word.

```
text= text.lower()
for word in lst:
    matches_in_text = len(re.findall(word,text))
    if matches_in_text > 0:
        no_of_replaces = min(matches_in_text ,2)
        new_text= re.sub(word, '****',text,no_of_replaces )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the line

```
line = line.replace(word, '***',1)
```

which will replace the first instance of word.