# Counting occurrences of a word in a file

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I have no idea what to do. So this is the question:

Write a function that takes a filename and a word (or, if no word is given, assumes the word is “hello”), and returns an integer representing how many times that word appears in the file, except instances in the first line of the file don’t count.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider adding the code which you've tried and what was the result in the question so that we can see what can be improved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count one specific word in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401099/how-to-count-one-specific-word-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from pathlib import Path

def count(filename: str, word = "hello"):
    file = Path(filename)
        
    text = file.read_text()
    lines_excluding_first = text.split("\n")[1:]
    
    counts = sum([sum(list(map(lambda y: 1 if word == y else 0, x.split(" ")))) for x in lines_excluding_first])
    
    
    return counts
```

Example:
say you have a txt file like:

```
sample.txt
----------

this is the first line so this dose not count!
hello!! this is a sample text.
text which will be used as sample.
if nothing no word specified hellow is returned!
it will return the count.
```

```py
print(count("sample.txt")) 
## output: 2
```

#### EDIT:

I have made a small correction in the code now `"hellow!!"` and `"hellow"` are two separate words. Words are separated by blank spaces and than checked for equality. Therefore `"hellow"` and "hellow." are also different!

### As per the request here is how it will look on `repl.it`:

make a **sample.txt** first:
[image: sample.txt]
**main.py** looks like:
[image: main.py]
**you can see the output as 2 for default "hello"**
`[output is case sensitive i.e Hello and hello are not the same]`

Comment: Hope this helps :) if u have doubts about the code i will explain it !

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for helping me out! However, I still am not able to get any output from the code. Could it be because I am coding in repl.it?

Comment: Hy there, I tried it on repl.it and its working fine!! I will add two images in my answer but can you please mention in your question that you cant get output on repl.it

Comment: If you want code to ignore punctuations i.e `"hellow"` and `"hellow."` or `"hellow!!"` should be counted as `hellow` let me know. also if you want to make it case sensitive I can help. :)

Comment: Hi! So, would I have to write the sample.txt file as well for it to work? Just wanted to know and thank you for all of the time you have spent on answering my doubts and helping me expand knowledge of Python!

Comment: @GoodMovies yes you have to make a text file otherwise how will you open and read a non existing file. It can be any text file just make the necessary file name changes and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 2):

Call the function with two args, a filename that must be in path and the word to count inside the file. If you don't pass the word the function assumes the default word "hello".

```
def wordcount(filename, word="hello"):
    # Open the file name
    with open(filename) as file:
        # Skip first line
        next(file)  
        # read the file as a string except the first line and count the occurrences 
        return file.read().count(word)
```

Count method returns the number of occurrences of the substring in the given string. Also u can save the first line `x = next(file)` if you what to use it later.

Call the function and print the result with `print(wordcount("sample.txt", "repeat"))` to count how many times the word 'repeat' appears in the file.

The sample.txt contains:

```
Hello ! My name is João, i will repeat this !
Hello ! My name is João, i will repeat this !
Hello ! My name is João, i will repeat this !
Hello ! My name is João, i will repeat this !
Hello ! My name is João, i will repeat this !
```

The result must be 4 :)

Comment: Adding some commentary will go a long way to explain why this solves the OP's question. Just a code dump alone is not that helpful.

Comment: Simple questions need simple answers xp but i understand what ur saying !

Comment: @JoãoSantos your answer was quite correct but there is an issue with it. If you search for "i" than you will get output as `20` but you want output as `5`. `count() ` searches for occurrences of substring and not the actual word.

Comment: The whole point of SO is not answering one person's question, but to have a repository of questions-answers for anybody that might be facing similar problems in the future. The extra commentary will serve those future visitors. Hence the entire voting system. See the [tour] for more info.