# Counting in how many documents does a word appear

Tags: python, loops, nlp, tf-idf

I'm trying to implement a TFIDF vectorizer without sklearn. I want to count the number of documents(list of strings) in which a  word appears, and so on for all the words in that corpus.
Example:

```
corpus = [
     'this is the first document',
     'this document is the second document',
     'and this is the third one',
     'is this the first document',
]
```

**Desired OP:** `{this : 4, is : 4}` and so on for every word

**My code:**

```
def docs(corpus):
    doc_count = dict()
    for line in corpus:
        for word in line.split():
            if word in line:
                doc_count[word] +=1
            else:
                doc_count[word] = 1
        print(counts)

docs(corpus)
```

**Error I'm facing:**

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-6bf2b69708bc> in <module>
      9         print(counts)
     10 
---> 11 docs(corpus)

<ipython-input-70-6bf2b69708bc> in docs(corpus)
      4         for word in line.split():
      5             if word in line.split():
----> 6                 doc_count[word] +=1
      7             else:
      8                 doc_count[word] = 1

KeyError: 'this'
```

Please let me know where I'm lacking and if I'm not iterating properly. Thank you!

Comment: Your logic make no sense. You split line and are iterating over each word. But you are checking if that word exists in that line? Pretty sure is going to be always true. It literally comes from the line split.

Comment: You seem to have a typo. `if word in line` is trivially true because that's where it came from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count one specific word in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401099/how-to-count-one-specific-word-in-python)

Comment: @Goion Thank you for pointing out the logic mistake, that is exactly where I was wrong. Also, the other link is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
corpus = [
     'this is the first document',
     'this document is the second document',
     'and this is the third one',
     'is this the first document',
]

def docs(corpus):
    doc_count = dict()
    for line in corpus:
        for word in line.split():
            #you did mistake here
            if word in doc_count:
                doc_count[word] +=1
            else:
                doc_count[word] = 1
    return doc_count    

ans=docs(corpus)
print(ans)
```